# proving the Neumann BVP has a solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

If we are given a cylinder with a radius of two meters. How can we show that if the electric field is $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(2, \theta)=\cos (\theta)$ on the surface of the cylinder, then the Neumann BVP has a solution. Im not quite sure what the best way to approach this problem is. I was told it is as simple as integrating $cos\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$ but I don't quite see the reasoning behind that. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: $u=r\cos(\theta)$ is one solution

Comment: What do you mean with $\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}(2, \theta)$? $\partial_r u(r, \theta) $ evaluated at $r = 2 $ and angle $\theta$?